# Can't get jQuery addClass("active") to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

This is a bit of a simplification of my code, but I think the example works. Basically, what I want to do is to use jQuery to automatically highlight a selected div-element.

At the moment, the div-element only seems "active" once I hold down on the element (the background becomes orange).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Samuels HTML-inlämning!</title>



            <script type="text/javascript"     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js">
    </script>



    <script type="text/javascript">


            $('.test').click(function(){
                $('.test').removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
            });


    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        div.test{
            background: grey;
        }

        div.test:hover{
            background: yellow;
        }

        div.test.active{
            background: orange;
        }


    </style>

</head>


    <body>


            <div class="test">
                Stuff
            </div>
            <div class="test">
                Other stuff
            </div>
            <div class="test">
                More Stuff
            </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work? The complete example works basically the same, but I an ID to select the class to be un-highlighted rather than (.test) all classes. But that code produces the same result.

UPDATE:

Tried making this change in CSS:

```
        div.test.active{
            background: orange;
        }
```

Now it doesn't highligt at all however. Did I miss something?

Comment: active is not a class it is a pseudo class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because you are setting the property in your CSS as a pseudo-class, Try this:

```
    div.test.active{
        background: orange;
    }
```

Comment: You have a typo in the selector, it should be div.test:active :)

Comment: Thats intended. it's not a typo.

Comment: Pseudo selectors are added with : not with the point.. He confused the addClass with active pseudo state.

Comment: @Goran.it, @taxicala is right, since the OP specifically refers to the `.active` class and not the `:active` pseudo-class

Comment: I dont whant to use a pseudo-class, I am telling him to change his code in order to use .active in his CSS, so that the addClass works and he doesn't have to change anything else than a simple character in his code...

Comment: I tried that. Now it doesn't highligt at all. Changed in CSS to div.test.active.

Comment: can you paste the code? maybe a jsfiddle could help a lot to solve this.

Comment: You missed a "." in your code: div.testactive should be div.test.active :)

Comment: I created a fiddle, but it totally worked! Tried the exact in aptana/firefox. Didn't work.

Comment: Maybe the version of jquery you are using?

Comment: Yeah, there code seems to work fine. It must be something else. I'm trying to figure it out now, but it seems like my question has been answered.

Comment: Anyway, I pasted the entire html doc above if you wanna have a look. Of some reason it doesn't work while the jsfiddle one does. Strange...

Comment: I am checking, anyhow you should accept the answer in order to future users that come along with an issue simmilar to yours know that this solves it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing classes and state selectors. :active is a state (that means you're currently mouse-down on it) while .active is any random class (it could be .xyz). Here's more information on states: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/